# Select raster tiles within vector polygons

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, select-by-location

I have a shapefile with polygons of all the countries of the world. I also have a raster `.tiff` (250m square pixels) of average wind speed per pixel.

I want to select all the tiles which lie within each country polygon so I end up with lots of individual raster files which correspond to every single country.

I know there will be border/overlap issues but it's supposed to be general. How can I do this in QGIS?

Comment: When you say "select all the tiles" do you actually mean "select all the pixels"? Because you didn't mention tiles anywhere else.

Answer (score 3):

Use the SAGA tool `Clip raster with polygon`. This tool can be found in the Processing Toolbox.

Click the round green arrow button next to the Polygons layer. This button toggles the option to

> Iterate over this layer, creating a separate output for every feature in the layer.

[image]